# appending data dynamically to table using jquery and it will get only one row when downloded

Tags: html, jquery

This is my .gohtml page. I am trying to incorporate bootstrap theme(minible admin). Please guide how to use it.if anyone has its documentation please refer. here i am trying to use it's datatable with "export to excel,pdf" function. it is exported to excel but only one row of table gets copied not the whole table. I tried a lot but cannot able to solve.Please help!

the code is as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("/norm/Pune/2021-08-02", function(data) {
    if (!data) {
      return
    }
    
    var table = document.getElementById('datatable-buttons')

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = `<tr>
                     <td>${data[i].date}</td>
                     <td>${data[i].location}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].Part_number}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].Norm}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].Item_category}</td>
                        </tr>`

      table.innerHTML += row
    } //for
  });
})
```

```css
#datatable-buttons {
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border-spacing: 0; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

        <h4 class="card-title">Buttons example</h4>
        <p class="card-title-desc">The Buttons extension for DataTables provides a common set of options, API methods and styling to display buttons on a page that will interact with a DataTable. The core library provides the based framework upon which plug-ins can built.
        </p>

        <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
          <thead>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Norm</th>
            <th>Item Category</th>
          </thead>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

Comment: [File export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

Comment: [HTML5 export buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)